# Single overhead cam non VTEC swap to dual overhead cam VTEC

Tags: engine, honda, accord, vtec

so I'm thinking about changing the single overhead cam non VTEC f22b over to a f22a dual overhead cam VTEC engine in my 93 Accord I want to know what problems I'm going to run into the ECU and wiring harness

Comment: there are several questions about vtec, here is one that may help you : https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/17090/10976